# Close button not having "X" in Fluent UI

Tags: fluent-ui, office-fabric, fluentui-react

I'm trying to create a [TeachingBubble](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/teachingbubble) using Fluent UI. I want it to have close button, marked with "x".
I'd like to have a closing button like in this example:

[image]

How can that be done in react, using Fluent UI?

My current code:

```
import { TeachingBubble } from "@fluentui/react";

interface IOnboardingProps {
  actionFunction?: () => void;
  closeFunction?: () => void;
}

const Onboarding2: React.FC<IOnboardingProps> = ({
  actionFunction = () => {},
  closeFunction = () => {},
}) => {
  return (
    <TeachingBubble
      headline="How to get started"
      hasCloseButton={true}
      closeButtonAriaLabel="Blabla"
      onDismiss={() => {
        console.log("Close button pressed.");
        closeFunction();
        console.log("Passed function done.");
      }}
      primaryButtonProps={{ children: "Done", onClick: () => actionFunction() }}
    >
      Some instructions
    </TeachingBubble>
  );
};

export default Onboarding2;
```

And this is what I get:

The close button exists but it doesn't have an "X". I thought "X" was added by default when "hasCloseButton" is set to true.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why "x" icon was not rendered is because icons were not initialized. That's done by adding:

```
import { initializeIcons } from "@fluentui/react/lib/Icons";

initializeIcons();
```